# Right Triangle Hypotenuse in a right triangle (Quadratic Equation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The hypotenuse of a right triangle is $5 m$ if the smaller is doubles and longer is triples the new hypotenuse is $6\sqrt{5} m$. FInd the sides of the triangle.

What I found so far: After coming up the equation in both we will come upon a case where we will find a quadratic equation in one variable where we will have to apply Discriminant Formula or Factorisation formula to come up with the solution.

Comment: So what is the difficulty? Have you found the quadratic equation, but you can't solve it?

Comment: Nope, I can easily find the solution. But I am having difficulty in coming up with that Quadratic Equation. How can I get that Quadratic Equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
$$x^2 + y^2=5^2$$
$$x^2 = 25-y^2$$
2.
$$(2x)^2 + (3y)^2 = (6\sqrt{5})^2$$
$$4x^2 + 9y^2 = 180$$
3. Substitute $x^2 = 25-y^2$
$$4(25-y^2) + 9y^2 = 180$$
$$100-4y^2+9y^2=180$$
$$5y^2=80$$
$$y^2=16$$
$$y=4$$
$$x=3$$
Negative root rejected because side lengths are positive.